# Bootstrap Navbar getting stuck in responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a simple website using a bootstrap theme.

I have created a navbar in it.

The navbar collapses in responsive mode but it sticks to the right side of the page which is forcing me to scroll horizantally to click the dropdown menu.

[image]

What exactly is wrong here?

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.05);
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  color: #424242;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #424242;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #424242;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #424242;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
  color: #424242;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #424242 !important;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > li.active > a:focus:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #424242;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #424242;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #424242;
  }
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default.affix .nav > li > a:focus:hover {
    color: #424242;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top" style="padding-top:0px">
        <img style="width:150px;height:50px" src="img/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="font-family:Roboto">
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#aboutg" style="text-transform:capitalize">About G-Suite</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio" style="text-transform:capitalize">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#gform" style="text-transform:capitalize">Enquiry</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#pricing" style="text-transform:capitalize">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact" style="text-transform:capitalize">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: where is the dropdown-toggle supposed to be?

Comment: Could you provide link of your site or a working fiddle? debugging would be more easier.

Comment: I edited the post so we can run the code snippet you provided, but it doesn't show off the error you're seeing. Could you add a minimal snippet to the HTML to show what the problem is?

Comment: www.appslogix.in @AbhishekPandey

Comment: @redbmk thanks for the edit and I have given the link to the website in the above comment.

Comment: I think all the navbar code in the question is pretty misleading. I see what you're talking about if I start at full screen and then switch to emulating an iPhone 6 Plus in devtools. If I remove the navbar there is still a big gap on the right side. Also, if I refresh the page with it already emulating the device, it looks fine. Maybe you have some javascript on the page that's acting on resize events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your pricing section

**Remove** the width from .tooltipx .tooltiptexty **for mobile devices**

```
width: 250px;
```

or make it

```
width: auto;
```

Comment: But if I don't put the width the tooltip overlaps the text in the table.